# Add suffix number to duplicated groups and add rows for duplicated values in a df in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df  such as

```
Type   Species     Value
Dog    Species2    100
Dog    Species1    200
Dog    Species3    300
Dog    Species3    900
ALL_   Species1    400
ALL_   Species2    500
ALL_   Species3    600
```

how can I add rows to `ALL_` for each duplicated Species while also adding a `suffix_number` to the duplicated Species in `ALL_` and `DOG`

I should then get :

```
Type   Species     Value
Dog    Species2    100
Dog    Species1    200
Dog    Species3_1  300
Dog    Species3_2  900
ALL_   Species1    400
ALL_   Species2    500
ALL_   Species3_1  600
ALL_   Species3_2  600
```

Here is the dataframe if it can helps :

```
data = {'Type': ['Mammuthus', 'Mammuthus', 'Mammuthus', 'Mammuthus', 'ALL_', 'ALL_', 'ALL_'],
        'Species': ['Species2', 'Species1', 'Species3', 'Species3', 'Species1', 'Species2', 'Species3'],
        'Value': [100, 200, 300, 900, 400, 500, 600]}
```